# Creating review by code is not setting the created_at

Tags: magento-2.1, review

I am creating reviews on **Magento 2.1** using the **factory** and setting the **created_at** but it seems magento is ignoring it.

```
$review = $this->reviewFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                        'created_at' => $myReview->createdAt,
                        'updated_at' => $myReview->updatedAt,
                        'stores' => $this->getAllStoreIds(),
                        'code' => $myReview->id,
                        'status_id' => Review::STATUS_APPROVED
                    ]
                ]
            );
```

It does create the review but without created_at

Comment: nesisantos, is my solution  worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can not see  the **created_at date**  of review*, Because of of magento,itself  set **CreatedAt field value** to current ***`gmt time`*** at during review creation.

See at  `Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review` at  function `_beforeSave`

```
 protected function _beforeSave(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if (!$object->getId()) {
            $object->setCreatedAt($this->_date->gmtDate());
        }
```

So, you can  set created using default review code.

**Solution:**

*If you want to force fully then you need  do some code,*

create an **around  plugin** for  function **_beforeSave**

```
 public function aroundBeforeSave(
     \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review $subject ,
     \Closure $proceed ,
     \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object
 )
 {
        $result = $proceed($object);
        $isNew = $object->isObjectNew();
         // force to set for new  
        if($isNew){
            $object->setCreatedAt($object->getForceDate()); 
        }
        return $result;
 }
```

First, you need set a custom setter function `'forced_date' => $myReview->createdAt()` instead of `'created_at' => $myReview->createdAt,`

Comment: You can't add a plugin to a protected method